# Error in Angular ng serve static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef<ShepherdService>

Tags: angular, npm

I had to install a project in another pc, I use Angular v 9.1.0 but after I run npm install I have this error:

> ERROR in node_modules/angular-shepherd/lib/shepherd.service.d.ts:64:18 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ɵɵFactoryDef' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> 64     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDef;

I have the same version of the package in both pc `angular-shepherd": "^0.5.0`

I already tried to remove and reinstall node_modules and also the package angular-shepherd but I still have the error.
In the old pc, all works well.
If it helps this is the package:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^4.4.5-beta",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
    "angular-shepherd": "^0.5.0",
    "animate.css": "3.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.7",
    "i18n-iso-countries": "^5.1.0",
    "intl-tel-input": "^16.0.11",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsbarcode": "^3.11.0",
    "latinize": "^0.4.0",
    "material-community-components": "^6.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.28",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.7",
    "ng2-password-strength-bar": "^1.2.3",
    "ng2-tel-input": "2.3.0",
    "ngx-barcode6": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "latest",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^4.0.2",
    "ngx-image-zoom": "^0.6.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^8.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "placeholder-loading": "^0.2.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^9.0.0",
    "print-js": "^1.0.63",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^8.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.3.2",
    "@types/chartist": "0.9.48",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.10",
    "@types/jquery": "3.3.34",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.5",
    "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "cypress": "^4.1.0",
    "cypress-plugin-tab": "^1.0.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4",
    "protractor": "^5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.8.1",
    "tslint": "6.1.0",
    "typescript": "3.8.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

I was having this error today as well. My issue was the version of "@angular/compiler-cli" in my main project was 9.1, but in the library I was importing (it was a local node module), it was using 9.0. I updated the library to use 9.1 and that fixed it for me.

In your case, looks like [this](https://github.com/shipshapecode/angular-shepherd/blob/master/package.json) is running an older version of the compiler, so you might have to change the version in your project so that they match. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the upgrade to angular 9.1.
When updating to 9.1, ngcc doesn't seem to handle the conversion well.
Remove the lib and reinstall it, it should fix the issue